# Initializing C++11 threads from within an if statement

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, compiler-errors, g++

I am implimenting threads in C++11 and experienceing a compilation issue whenever I initiate a thread from within an if statement.

The error I am receiving is:

```
file.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
file.cpp:16:2: error: ‘thread1’ was not declared in this scope
  thread1.join();
```

When I move the thread outside of an if statement everything compiles and runs fine.

I am using g++ version 4.8.2 and using the -std=c++11 compiler option.

This code will not compile

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void testthread() {
    std::cout << "Thread was run" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {

    if (true) {
        std::thread thread1(testthread);
    }
    sleep(1);
    thread1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and runs as expected

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void testthread() {
    std::cout << "Thread was run" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {

    std::thread thread1(testthread);
    sleep(1);
    thread1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `thread1` does not exist outside the scope of your `if` statement, there has to be many duplicates of this type of question.

Comment: The problem should be immediately obvious from the very clear error message ... but perhaps you don't know what a scope is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The body of an `if()` statement is a block scope so the lives any variables created within it are bound to its scope. This means that `thread1` isn't accessible outside of the `if()` statement.

Instead you can default construct the thread and then assign it to a new one:

```
std::thread thread1;

if (true) {
    thread1 = std::thread(testthread)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the thread variable inside the if block. It is only visible there.
If you really need to initialize it inside the if block and use it outside, you can use a pointer and allocate it inside the if block.

```
std::thread* pThread1 = nullptr;
if (true) {
        pThread1 = new std::thread(testthread);
}
sleep(1);
pThread1->join();
delete(pThread1);
```